# PostGIS installation on Ubuntu 10.12 (Amazon Services)

Tags: postgis, installation, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

On Ubuntu 10.12 (AMI on Amazon), I use `aptitude` to install Postgresql and PostGis. 
On terminal running psql interactive prompt, I type `CREATE EXTENSION postgis` and

ERROR:  could not open extension control

> file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.1/extension/postgis.control": No such
>   file or directory

Is there something I forgot to install?

Comment: Might be easier to use a pre-configured AMI https://aws.amazon.com/amis/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i can install postgre 9.2 and postgis 2.03 using:

**-- INSTALL POSTGRESQL**

-- remove previous version

sudo apt-get remove postgresql

-- require

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

-- add new repository

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pitti/postgresql
sudo apt-get update

-- install postgresql

sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.2 postgresql-common postgresql-server-dev-9.2 postgresql-contrib-9.2  postgresql-client-9.2

-- command for start or stop  the service

sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start

sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop

*-- opcional if show error for character local setting use:

*sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8*   -- or other you need*

*-- configure file are in

/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/*

*-- if need change password to user postgres in linux use:

sudo passwd postgresql*

**-- install pgadmin**

-- if exist previous version

sudo apt-get remove pgadmin3

-- add repository

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:voronov84/andreyv

-- install

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install pgadmin3

**-- INSTALL POSTGIS 2.0.3**

-- require

sudo apt-get install build-essential libproj-dev

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libjson0-dev xsltproc docbook-xsl docbook-mathml

sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev

-- dowbnload an install GEOS

wget http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.3.8.tar.bz2

tar xvfj geos-3.3.8.tar.bz2

cd geos-3.3.8

./configure

make

sudo make install

cd ..

-- Download and install postgis

wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.0.3.tar.gz

tar xfvz postgis-2.0.3.tar.gz

cd postgis-2.0.3

./configure

make

sudo make install

sudo ldconfig

sudo make comments-install

-- configure

sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql

sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp

sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/raster2pgsql

--in psql

su postgres

psql

CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology;

CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;

\q

-- prepare template if you need

------ postgis

sudo -u postgres psql template1

sudo -u postgres createdb template_postgis

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -c "UPDATE pg_database SET datistemplate=true WHERE datname='template_postgis'"

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/contrib/postgis-2.0/postgis.sql

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/contrib/postgis-2.0/spatial_ref_sys.sql

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/contrib/postgis-2.0/postgis_comments.sql

---- raster

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/contrib/postgis-2.0/rtpostgis.sql

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/contrib/postgis-2.0/raster_comments.sql

---- topology

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/contrib/postgis-2.0/topology.sql

sudo -u postgres psql -d template_postgis -f /usr/share/postgresql/9.2/contrib/postgis-2.0/topology_comments.sql

---

ok

thanks

Dante

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how complicated it is. But it works. Saves me a bunch of time. Thanks you so much.

Comment: installing this stuff reminds me of the movie "The Way Back" --- a true **rubicon**

Comment: Dante - massive thank you from me for a detailed set of instructions. Solved a big problem for me

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS is now officialy supported by amazon RDS. That makes things very easy as explained in [Setting up PostGIS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS).

See also [PostGIS on Amazon RDS: A Spatial Database in the Cloud](http://blog.safe.com/2013/12/postgis-on-aws-rds/).